# assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core-1.1

We have a website being deployed on site and it is failing to start up. It is a .NET Core 1.1.2 application and when using the command line:

dotnet Website.dll we get the following error:

"Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was noto found -- package: 'system.data.sqlclient', version: '4.4.0', path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Data.SqlClient.dll'"

I'm not normally involved with the deployments so this was has got me baffled. If it's any help, this is a debug build, not relelase (Don't ask!)

Any help/suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was as simple as it was packaged with the wrong dll! Once the correct dll was supplied it started up as it should have.